# Mysql procedure to update difference between two dates for all records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table with two dates and their difference

```
TABLE
Posting date     Expiry Date       Days Left
30-Mar-2014      30-April-2013      31
30-Mar-2014      30-April-2013      31
31-Mar-2014      30-April-2013      30
```

How can I create a procedure  to update, calculate *Days Left* from current date (not posting date but the system date) to Expiry date for each record.

I am in doubt if I should store **Days Left** in database currently its facilitates user to sort record according to days left to expire.

Comment: Your differences seem unrelated to the dates in the table.  Can you fix the sample data and provide the desired results that you want for this sample data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff days left will calculated daily i.e. Expiry Date - Todays Date(System Date) and result days updated to Days Left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like:

```
update tableName set DaysLeft = DATEDIFF(ExpiryDate, NOW())
```

You could put that in a stored proc, but it's just one line.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you want something of the following:

```
SELECT datediff(ExpiryDate,NOW()) AS E FROM MyTable ORDER BY E DESC
```